# Multi Select Box in Codename one

Tags: codenameone

Currently, I am using Combo Box component for single selection, now I required Multiselection for to select multiple items at a time, I am searched for MultiSelection component in Codename one but I didn't find.
Please help me how to achieve multi-selection in codename one.

Answer (score 2):

Create a box layout y Form with checkboxes for your selections